# Data variable to cookie wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to create a cookie with data from a variable. This variable is filled on a specific blog post. What is the way to get the data from this variable and set it in the cookie?

Wordpress set cookie works only in the functions.php file.

This is what I have

```
function cookietime($time) { 
    if(!isset($_COOKIE[$wp_time])) {
        // sessin cookie filled with data from $time
        setcookie('wp_time', $time);
    }
 } 
add_action('placeCookie', 'cookietime', 10, 1);
```

This code is writin in the functions.php

```
do_action('cookietime', $parameter);
//this line on the specific post
```

Comment: Setcookie is a header function. That means it has to be called before any output.

Comment: Andreas, okey but how can I fill this with a variable input?